# Newton JSON How to serialize object to empty brackets?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a generic class of objects

```
public class MyClass
{     
   [Required]
   public string Title { get; set; }

   [Required]
   public int OrderIndex { get; set; }
}
```

After reading of database have filled members

`var myClass= await readValues();`

So, values are not null.

```
myClass: [{
      "title": "example title",
      "orderIndex": 5
}]
```

But I need to return it as empty object after serialize like below

`myClass: []`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Before serializing, you can do `myClass = new myClass[0];`